# Shadows change between different three.js versions

Tags: javascript, three.js

Spot light shadow changes between revision 45 and 65. Example picture cube in different versions. Version 45 behavior is that one that I try achieve, using version 65. Seems that 65 add more shadows. Many they change light or material settings.

[image]

Comment: looks like back then, the plane material did not have per pixel shading activated/did not use it. This has nothing to do with "shadows" as the cube's shadow is the same.
Also, do you have any specific question at all? :D

Comment: Can i turn off pixel shading ?

Comment: hmm, well.... seems that in the latest versions the per-pixel options are removed, i think. see:
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/commit/30a4eaea880c909dd6633795d3d0641cc2a8d5d7
i guess you could quickly implement your own vertex/pixel shader with vertex-lighting.

Comment: You need to modify your post and specify your exact geometry parameters, material parameter, and lighting parameters.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that recent versions of three.js render surfaces lit by a spotlight more correctly than old versions.  If you want the scene to look like the first figure, you should either place the spotlight farther from the plane or even replace the spotlight with a directional light.